Shopware Admin API post new product with postman
Screenshot Postman post request
I have been experiencing difficulties for a few days with the following issue:
I am trying to create a new product via the Admin API using Postman. Unfortunately, the server responds with a list of all products instead of adding the new product.
I have created the request according to the Shopware Admin API documentation:
Url: POST "http://shop.de/api/product"
Parameters: Accept: application/json, Content-Type: application/json
Body:
{ 
  "name": "test", 
  "productNumber": "random", 
  "stock": 10, 
  "taxId": "a5da76b447db4d0aba62e6512dadf45b", 
  "price": [ 
    { 
      "currencyId": "b7d2554b0ce847cd82f3ac9bd1c0dfca", 
      "gross": 15, 
      "net": 10, 
      "linked": false 
    }
  ] 
}

I have taken the values for taxId and currencyId from existing products. Could the issue be with the URL endpoint or somewhere else? I would appreciate any help!
Best regards,
Sevki
I tried to post a new product using the Shopware Admin API with Postman, but the server responds with a list of all products instead of creating a new product.

Everything about your request is completely correct.
If you receive a product list from http://shop.tld/api/product you have used the request type GET instead of POST.
I have double checked it in a local installation.
POST will create your product:

GET will get you a list of all products:

A common reason for accidental use of GET is a redirect from http:// to https:// or from non-www. to www.. You might want to check for that.

Hello, thank you for your response. I have attached a screenshot showing that I used POST as the request type, but the server is responding as if it were a GET request for all products. Could you please share a screenshot of your POST request?

@sevki330 The most common reason for mistakes of this type is a redirect taking place. Redirects by definition change the request type and the post data gets lost. Can you double check, if "http" is the correct protocol? A lot of sites redirect to "https". The same applies to a "www." prefix to the host name. If nothing works, feel free to send me testing credentials. (contact data in my profile)

Actually i changed "http" to "https" and it worked! The question is why it is stated as "http" in the documentation.

Probably because http is common in localhost environments which are often used for development.
